# How to set id of a socket in WebSocket?

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I'm using: https://github.com/websockets/ws as websockets.

In socket.io you could give an id to your sockets like:

```
io.emit('id','myText');

io.on('id',function(data){
    //read data
});
```

In websocket on the server you can read sockets by id.

```
ws.on('id', function (data) {

};
```

You can read sockets by id on the client too.

```
ws.addEventListener('id', function (data) {

};
```

But I couldn't find how to send a socket with a specific id, I've also checked the code base. Am I missing something or is this impossible? Or are there some hacks that could achieve this?

```
//I want this:
ws.send('id','myText');
```

Comment: For one webSocket to send to another, you need to invent your own message that the client sends to the server that instructs the server to then send that message to a specific other client.  This is not built into the webSocket protocol.  You just have to implement it yourself in your own server.  Further, the plain webSocket protocol does not have custom message names like socket.io does.  It has one generic "message" that means data arrived from the other end.  If you want to have your own sub-message names, you have to include them in your data so you code can look inside the data packet.

Comment: FYI, there is no `ws.on('id', function(data) { ... });` in webSocket.  You listen for data with `ws.on('message', function(data) { ... });`.  If you want to send a particular message name, you send that inside the `data` that is sent.  For example, `data` could be an object that you had `data.messageName` set to whatever you want for each message.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that method was a last resort for me if no alternatives were present.

Comment: Well, it's not a last resort because it isn't supported at all.  It appears like you're trying to use a socket.io API with a webSocket.  That simply doesn't work.  socket.io adds a layer on top of webSocket to add things like message names.  If you want to use that type of layer with a plain webSocket, you have to implement it yourself on top of a webSocket (or just use socket.io at both ends and use its already completed implementation).

Comment: Yeah, just implemented a layer. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll format my comments into an answer since it appears to have explained things for you:

There is no handler for your own message names like this in webSocket:

```
ws.on('id', function(data) { ... });
```

Instead, you listen for data with this:

```
ws.on('message', function(data) { ... });
```

If you want to send a particular message name, you send that inside the data that is sent. For example, data could be an object that you had `data.messageName` set to whatever you want for each message.

It appears like you're trying to use a socket.io API with a webSocket. That simply doesn't work. socket.io adds a layer on top of webSocket to add things like message names. If you want to use that type of layer with a plain webSocket, you have to implement it yourself on top of a webSocket (or just use socket.io at both ends).